# Why don't previously selected GridView items show as selected?

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows 8 App that uses a GridView to display a collection of Items. I've created the app using C# and XAML. The GridView is multi-selectable.

When the user leaves the GridView page I save which items in the grid were selected, to application state, using:  `navigationHelper_SaveState().`

When the user returns to the GridView page I want to re-select the previously selected items.

I've confirmed that both saving and loading state work.

However, the previously selected items don't get selected when the user returns to the page. From within `navigationHelper_LoadState().` I do this to select all of the previously selected items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPrevSelectedItems; i++) {    
  ItemsGridView.SelectedItems.Add(items[i]);
}
```

Elsewhere on StackOverflow I've read that using `SelectedItems.Add()` should work. However, it does not work for me. No previously selected items are visibly selected when the user returns to the page.

Interestingly enough, `ItemsGridView.SelectAll();` does work.

What's the best way to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Get the selected rows
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection SelectedRowsCollection = ItemsGridView.SelectedRows;

// Clear your ItemsGridView selected rows (Just for testing the following code)
ItemsGridView.ClearSelection();

// Get your previous selected rows again.
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in SelectedRowsCollection)
{
    int idx = ItemsGridView.Rows.IndexOf(item);
    ItemsGridView.Rows[idx].Selected = true;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I did an experiment and added an Item from the GridView itself to the ItemsGridView.SelectedItems. This worked. That led me to realize that because I was re-serializing the selected items via a JSON string that captured app state, that the SelectedItems were not pointing to the actual Item instances in the GridView.